# Assigning a random score based on max value of grouped data using R

Tags: r

Consider a sample dataframe;

```
| cat_name | brand_name | qty | amt |
-------------------------------------
|  A       |     AA     |  10 | 500 |
|  A       |     AB     |  8  | 400 |
|  A       |     AC     |  10 | 100 |
|  B       |     BA     |  20 | 250 |     
|  B       |     BB     |  05 | 150 |
|  B       |     BC     |  10 | 100 |
```

I would like to assign a score based on the max value of the amount for each group present in the dataframe, for example, for the above dataset, I can provide the below sample score;

```
| cat_name | brand_name | qty | amt |  score |
----------------------------------------------
|  A       |     AA     |  10 | 500 |   100  |
|  A       |     AB     |  8  | 400 |   80   |
|  A       |     AC     |  10 | 100 |   30   |
|  B       |     BA     |  20 | 250 |   100  |  
|  B       |     BB     |  05 | 150 |   75   |
|  B       |     BC     |  10 | 100 |   30   |
```

As said, I will assign a value based on 0 - 100 as score and then for each group in the dataset based on the amount max and min value, I will assign a score.

I can easily assign a random value based on the number of rows using sample.int(), but, is there a way where I can assign a specific value based on the max and min amount of each group in the dataframe. I will be generally grouping by cat_name.

Comment: Its better to include your rule of giving scores like why 100 for cat_name A got 30 and why 500 got 100

Comment: I am just giving random score between 0 to 100, based on the value of amt field. For example, for each category I can assign score based on the max value of the amt. The higher the amount, the higher the score.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `dplyr` to group by `cat_name` and `brand_name`. It then samples between the min and max `amt` for that group and assigns it to a new column with `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(cat_name,brand_name) %>%
  mutate(score = sample(seq(min(amt),max(amt)),n(),replace = TRUE))
## A tibble: 6 x 5
## Groups:   cat_name, brand_name [6]
#  cat_name brand_name   qty   amt score
#  <fct>    <fct>      <int> <int> <int>
#1 A        AA            10   500   466
#2 A        AB             8   400   167
#3 A        AC            10   100    12
#4 B        BA            20   250    54
#5 B        BB             5   150    73
#6 B        BC            10   100    85
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(cat_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), brand_name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AA", 
"AB", "AC", "BA", "BB", "BC"), class = "factor"), qty = c(10L, 
8L, 10L, 20L, 5L, 10L), amt = c(500L, 400L, 100L, 250L, 150L, 
100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks, its close enough. But, I would like to assign max score to the one with higher amount. In this case, for cat_name A, I would give it 100, 80, 30. My score range is between 100 to 0. The higher the amount the higher value of score, the lower the amount the lesser the score.